# Exploding string and putting values in <select>

Tags: javascript, php, input, explode

I have a column in my db, tip_sting:
1 row example(each one has the same format):

`G1-11, G2-21, P2-50, P4-20, P100-2,`

I'm using this when editing a item(I want to create(as many selects in the string) and put the values automaticaly in the select) :

https://jsfiddle.net/avrzwt6k/

So I was thinking of doing something like:

```
$pieces = explode(",", $tip_stingu);
$a=count($pieces); // piece1
echo $a;
echo '<br>';
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
echo '<br>';
$tip_stinga=explode("-",$pieces);
```

I just dont know how could I continue?

Comment: Do you want to place the select box dynamically with javascript?

Comment: @H.Jabi Doesn't matter as long I get the result I want(some selects with the queried values)

Comment: Then you can proceed with @SLWS's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need something like this?

```
<?php

$items = "G1-11, G2-21, P2-50, P4-20, P100-2";

$pieces = explode(",", $items);

echo ("<select>");
foreach ($pieces as $piece) {    
    $tip_stinga = explode("-", $piece);

    echo ('<option value="'.$tip_stinga[1].'">'.$tip_stinga[0].'</option>');
}
echo ("</select>");


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP & Javascript you can do:

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="example" name="example">
    <select name="myName" id="myID" onchange="updateText()">
        <?php
            $tip_stingu = "G1-11, G2-21, P2-50, P4-20, P100-2,";
            $pieces = explode(', ', $tip_sting);
            $piece1 = explode('-', $pieces[0])[1];
            foreach($pieces as $piece) {
                $tip_stinga = explode("-", $piece);
                echo ('<option value="'.$tip_stinga[1].'">'.$tip_stinga[0].'</option>');
            }
echo '</select><input type="text" value="'.$piece1.'" id="quantity" /><br />'
    ?>

</form>

    <script>
    function updateText() {
        document.getElementById("quantity").value = document.getElementById("myID").value;
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

You also have a trailing comma at the end of your example, if that's a problem you can use:

```
echo ('<option value="'.rtrim($tip_stinga[1], ',').'">'.$tip_stinga[0].'</option>');
```

instead of:

```
echo ('<option value="'.$tip_stinga[1].'">'.$tip_stinga[0].'</option>');
```